# Could someone suggest a vanilla javascript texture/polygon mapper for canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I am doing a small project on computer vision and face swapping and would
like to get some feedback for a very fast texture mapping function
using vanilla javascript.

I have in my posession a somewhat effecient version which uses setTransform
and clipping, however the inbuilt JS clipping is far too slow.

I am using the following

```
 function canvasTextureMapper (handle,sindex,count,zeee,zeeeoi,xyuv0,xyuv1,xyuv2,xyuv3,img)
 {
 var len,end,grp,c,t,i,j,k;
 var sx0,sy0,su0,sv0;
 var sx1,sy1,su1,sv1;
 var sx2,sy2,su2,sv2;
 var sx3,sy3,su3,sv3;
 var x0,x1,x2,u0,u1,u2;
 var y0,y1,y2,v0,v1,v2;
 var delta_0,delta_a,delta_b,delta_c,delta_d,delta_e,delta_f;
 var z0,z1,z2,z3;
 var zel,jjj,dep;

 if(aa_profiler.is_started) aaProfilerHit(callerName());
 if(xyuv0===undefined||xyuv0==null) { return false; }
 if(xyuv1===undefined||xyuv1==null) { return false; }
 if(xyuv2===undefined||xyuv2==null) { return false; }
 len=xyuv0.length;
 if(sindex<0)    { return false; }
 if(sindex>=len) { return false; }
 if(count<0)     { return false; }
 if(count==0)    { return false; }
 end=sindex+count;
 if(end>len)     { return false; }
 if((grp=aa.guiGroupGet(handle))==null) { return false; }
 if(xyuv3===undefined||xyuv3==null) { c=1; }
 else                               { c=2; }


 grp.ctx.save();
 grp.ctx.strokeStyle="";
 grp.ctx.fillStyle="";
 grp.ctx.lineWidth=0;

 //for(jjj=0;jjj<10;jjj++)
 {
 dep=jjj;
 //dep=5;
 for(j=0;j<count;j++)
  {
  k=sindex+j;
  i=k;
 // if(zeee[i]>dep) continue;
  sx0=xyuv0[i].x; sx1=xyuv1[i].x; sx2=xyuv2[i].x;
  sy0=xyuv0[i].y; sy1=xyuv1[i].y; sy2=xyuv2[i].y;
  su0=xyuv0[i].u; su1=xyuv1[i].u; su2=xyuv2[i].u;
  sv0=xyuv0[i].v; sv1=xyuv1[i].v; sv2=xyuv2[i].v;
  if(c>=2)
   {
   sx3=xyuv3[i].x;
   sy3=xyuv3[i].y;
   su3=xyuv3[i].u;
   sv3=xyuv3[i].v;
   }
  if(sx0==-12345) continue;
  grp.ctx.save();
  for(t=0;t<c;t++)
   {
   if(t==0) {  x0=sx0; x1=sx1; x2=sx2; y0=sy0; y1=sy1; y2=sy2; u0=su0; u1=su1; u2=su2; v0=sv0; v1=sv1; v2=sv2; }
   else     {  x0=sx2; x1=sx3; x2=sx0; y0=sy2; y1=sy3; y2=sy0; u0=su2; u1=su3; u2=su0; v0=sv2; v1=sv3; v2=sv0; }
   if(t==0&&1)
    {
    grp.ctx.beginPath();
    grp.ctx.moveTo(sx0,sy0);
    grp.ctx.lineTo(sx1,sy1);
    grp.ctx.lineTo(sx2,sy2);
    if(c==2) { grp.ctx.lineTo(sx3,sy3); }
    grp.ctx.closePath();
    grp.ctx.clip();
    }
   delta_0=u0*v1+v0*u2+u1*v2-v1*u2-v0*u1-u0*v2;
   delta_a=x0*v1+v0*x2+x1*v2-v1*x2-v0*x1-x0*v2;
   delta_b=u0*x1+x0*u2+u1*x2-x1*u2-x0*u1-u0*x2;
   delta_c=u0*v1*x2+v0*x1*u2+x0*u1*v2-x0*v1*u2-v0*u1*x2-u0*x1*v2;
   delta_d=y0*v1+v0*y2+y1*v2-v1*y2-v0*y1-y0*v2;
   delta_e=u0*y1+y0*u2+u1*y2-y1*u2-y0*u1-u0*y2;
   delta_f=u0*v1*y2+v0*y1*u2+y0*u1*v2-y0*v1*u2-v0*u1*y2-u0*y1*v2;
   grp.ctx.setTransform(delta_a/delta_0,(delta_d/delta_0),delta_b/delta_0,delta_e/delta_0,delta_c/delta_0,delta_f/delta_0);
   grp.ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
   }
  grp.ctx.restore();
  }

 }

 grp.ctx.restore();
 return true;
 }
```